# Quitar espacios en blanco de una serie

Tags: python, lista

Tengo una lista de esta forma, y necesito quitar los espacios entre palabras, es decir, para que quede así: 'jul07','jul08'...

Aqui dejo el código:

```
    FechasList = []
    for i in date:
         if i not in FechasList:
                     FechasList.append(i)
    print FechasList
    [u'Jul 07', u'Jul 08', u'Jul 10', u'Jul 11', u'Jul 12', u'Jul 13']
```

Comment: ¿La lista `date` puede tener fechas repetidas?

Comment: Si, de hecho, tiene varios 'jun 07', 'jun 07', 'jun 07', 'jun 08', jun 08....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que en un principio mencionas a Pandas y el uso de una "serie", presuponiendo que `datos` sea una serie de Pandas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
fechas_lista = data.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '')).unique()
```

Ten en cuenta que este método considera iguales `"Jul 12"` que `"Jul12"` o `" Jul 12"` y mantiene el orden de tu serie. Retorna un array de NumPy.

**Ejemplo:**

```
import pandas as pd

data  = pd.Series([u'Jul 07', u'Jul 08', u'Jul 10', u'Jul 11',
                   u'Jul 12', u'Jul 13', u'Jul 07', u'Jul 08',
                   u'Jul 10', u'Jul 11', u' Jul 07', u'Jul08 '])

fechas_lista = data.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '')).unique()
```

**Salida:**

> >>> fechas_lista
>   array(['Jul07', 'Jul08', 'Jul10', 'Jul11', 'Jul12', 'Jul13'], dtype=object)

Comment: Tal vez la más acertada si el OP confirma lo de Pandas

Comment: Corrió excelente, si es pandas, gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera:

```
import string
' hello  word'.translate(None, string.whitespace)
```

esto hace que se eliminen todos los espacios en blanco de tu string.

Saludos.

Comment: Elegante solución

Answer (score 3):

Aquí te muestro otra forma más de hacerlo usando *conjuntos comprehension* y las funciones `split()` y `join()`, para que tengas variedad:

```
fechas_lista = sorted({"".join(fecha.split()) for fecha in date})
```

Al ir creando un conjunto, los elementos repetidos desaparecen automáticamente. De esta manera, aun en el caso de tener una lista date del siguiente modo:

```
date = ['Jul 07', '  Jul  07', 'Jul 08', 'Jul 08  ']
```

La lista resultante no obtendría datos repetidos porque el conjunto es sobre las fechas con los espacios ya quitados, por lo tanto el cjto elimina automáticamente elementos repetidos por el contenido, aunque tengan espacios en blanco distintos.

Como los elementos del conjunto no tienen ningún orden predefinido, al llamar a `sorted()` pasándole por argumento el conjunto resultante te aseguras de dos cosas: obtienes una lista y además está ordenada.

*PD: Los identificadores que empiezan con mayúscula se suelen usar para crear clases o tipos de datos en lugar de variables.*

Comment: @César Es un conjunto. Lo puedes comprobar.

Comment: Es correcto, un error de mi parte al confundir los corchetes con los paréntesis

Comment: Sin problema @César. Te agradezco mucho tu observación. Una vez que me lo has dicho he ido a comprobar el tipo resultante por si acaso. Todo correcto.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ir quitando los espacios de la siguiente manera:

```
FechasList = []
for i in date:
    i = i.replace(' ', '')
    if i not in FechasList:
        FechasList.append(i)
print FechasList
```

Salida:

> [u'Jul07', u'Jul08', u'Jul10', u'Jul11', u'Jul12', u'Jul13']

Comment: ¿Seguro que funciona para el caso de que `date` tenga fechas repetidas? Porque, para cada elemento de `date` comprueba si no está en `FechasList`, pero es que en `FechasList` están las fechas recorridas hasta ahora de `date` sin espacios en blanco. Por lo tanto, si por ejemplo en `FechasList` está ya agregado `Jul07` e `i` tiene el valor `Jul 07`, la comprobación te dirá que no está en la lista y lo volverá a meter.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez no funciona tal y como dices. Si tiene fechas repetidas no las elimina como comentas y si no quiere eliminarlas el `if` solo empeora la pobre eficiencia del método por usar `append`... El OP tampoco parece interesarse mucho por los comentarios que se le dejan...

Comment: Blasito te recomiendo corregir el error. Para hacerlo todo en un solo for sin salirse de la idea del OP es necesario o bién usar `replace` dos veces (poco eficiente) o crear una variable intermedia. El `if` debe buscar la cadena sin espacios dentro de la lista no la que se obtiene directamente del `for`. Algo así: `i  = i.replace(' ', ''); if i not in FechasList: FechasList.append(i)`. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla Confirmo Blasito. Si editas y modificas como te indica en el anterior comentario FJSevilla se soluciona el error para fechas repetidas.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos los que observaron el detalle de error. No pude editarlo antes porque estaba viajando. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: No te preocupes, nadie tiene por qué estar pendiente a [es.so] continuamente. Lo importante es corregirlo en cuanto se pueda, por eso me gusta dejar un comentario y un tiempo prudencial antes de votar negativo u otra acciones. He editado la respuesta para corregir la identación de la línea siguiente al `if`, es solo un detalle pero ahora la respuesta es totalmente correcta. No es la forma más eficiente pero si que es la forma más cercana a la idea original del OP. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función `yourstring.replace(" ", "")` para quitar los espacios
o si solo quieres los de los lados puedes usar `yourstring.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con listas comprimidas:

```
FechaList = [f.replace(' ', '') for f in FechaList]
```

> La ventaja es que también puedes hacerlo de forma perezosa con `iteretor`, cambiando los `[` por `(`: `(f.replace(' ', '') for f in FechaList)` el cual se va ejecutando mientras se va recorriendo.

O también, puedes ejecutar un `map` con una función `lambda` para recorrer y convertir la lista en otra usando una función:

```
FechaList = map(lambda fecha: f.replace(' ', ''), FechaList)
```

> Ojo que `map` retorna un `map`, para convertirlo a lista debes hacer `list(FechaList)`

---

> **Misceláneo:** Cabe también mencionar que para lo que haces más arriba, lo de borrar repetidos, es mejor si usas `set`, quedando algo como `list(set(date))` que es una lista de valores únicos.

Comment: Si por ejemplo tienes un `date` con estos valores `['Jul 07', '  Jul 07']`, al llamar a `set(date)` no te eliminaría los repetidos porque son dos cadenas distintas.

Comment: Claro, eso es cierto, pero en su caso el está suponiendo que son totalmente iguales, por que hace `i not in FechasList`

Comment: Entiendo, pero su `i not in FechasList` es sobre la lista con las fechas ya modificadas, no sobre la lista de fechas original `date`. En el caso de que una de las fechas tenga un espacio de más, ya se duplicaría.

Comment: Es por que en principio, FechaList está vacía, y va llenando en ella, siempre y cuando el elemento a agregar ya no esté en la lista, es lo mismo que usar un set.

Comment: Sí, pero el `set()` lo haces sobre `date`, y si alguna de las fechas tiene un espacio de más ya no se considera igual a las otras fechas con su mismo valor. Por lo tanto, el resultado de `set(date)` te daría fechas repetidas que luego insertarías en `FechaList`

Comment: Ya te dije, que es cierto, pero su código tampoco hace esa validación.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón. Era solo por hacerlo lo más perfecto posible :)